# In DA:I, i cant answer my companions questions while we are exploring in the field

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

in DA:I, I can't answer my companions questions while we are in the field. I cant seem to find the mechanism by which i can address them. i see a grayed-out text bubble but i cant seem to access it. so instead, my character just remains silent and the conversation gets dropped. what am i missing here? thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 3):

You click with the right thunbstick

Comment: Correct assuming XBox controls.

Answer (score 0):

I got a glitch where right thumbstick doesn't work. In that case, when you see the gray bubble, try pulling up the potions menu (L1) and navigating the dialogue from there.